# mass editing page layouts of custom objects

Tags: page-layout

I need to add a section to almost all the page layouts of custom objects in our organisation.
is there any easy way of doing this that editing one by one...

Comment: nope!! AFAIK...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, but you can make it a lot easier by using e.g. Eclipse to edit the metadata:
Download all the layouts into Eclipse, find one where you already added the section manually, copy that  block and paste it into all other layouts that require the section.

Comment: Sorry, can't make it any better than this :-)